# Retaining TabBarController information

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I currently have a tabbed application set up in XCode. I have the main UITabController (called ViewController) connected to 2 different viewcontrollers by default. When the program loads, I have viewControllerOne loaded (the first tab) by default. When I select the second tab, the information retained in viewControllerOne is deleted (such as their properties). How do I go about retaining "Integers" when switching between the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View Controllers shouldn't be dealloc'd when you switch, but that's a separate issue.

Fundamentally, it would be a nicer architecture if your model data wasn't stored in your View Controller. Rather, create another model class (e.g. `UserDataManager : NSObject` which stores this information. Each View Controller would reference the same instance of this model class.

Comment: Thank you. I'm assuming the model would be a property in my first view, and make it strong/nonatomic. How would I go about accessing it in the other tabs?